Plane crash in desert
I'm looking for a movie where a plane crashes in desert.  The survivors play baseball to pass time.  As each one is found they disappear until there are not enough players for the game.
I think it was made in color.  It is not Flight of the Phoenix.  I'm pretty sure it was made after that movie.  Possibly starred a dark haired actor who is in Combat (TV series) or The Bridge at Remagen.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

For Flight of the Phoenix, do you mean the 1965 film or the 2004 film? Also, for the other two, do you mean this TV show and this film?

I meant either of 1965 film or the 2004 film.

It was not either version of the movie.  The dark haired man that I referred to was Vince Edwards and I am pretty sure he was in both - Combat (tv series and Bridge at Remagen, a great WW2 film.  Thank you for your help&interest

I believe you are looking for Sole Survivor from 1970. In it, B-25 bomber crashes on the way back from a mission. The ghosts of the dead crew members spend their time playing baseball as they wait for their bodies to be found and returned home so that they may have peace. As each body is found, the ghost disappears.

Yes. This is it.  I have trying to find this title for so long.  Thank you so every much!

Yes that's it.  Great movie.  Thank you so much.  I tried for a long time to remember.  Everyone always guessed Flight of the Phoenix.  Thanks again
